# Blazor - subscribing to a property value change

Tags: blazor

When working with components in Blazor, I often need the child component to react to a parameter changing value, and do something accordingly.

In a simple example, I have a UserId parameter linked between the parent and child components. The idea is that when the parent changes the UserId value, the property setter in the child invokes a method which reads the required data. Here is some code to illustrate.

**MyParent:**

```
<ChildComponent UserId="@UserId" />

<a onclick="@ChangeUser">Load User</a>

@code
{
   public int UserId = 0;
   
   void ChangeUser()
   {
      UserId = 1;
   }
}
```

**ChildComponent:**

```
@if(userDetails != null)
{
   <div>First Name: @userDetails.FirstName</div>
   <div>Surname: @userDetails.Surname</div>
}


@code
{
   private int _userId;
   
   [Parameter] public int UserId
   {
      get => _userId;
      set
      {
         _userId = value;
         LoadUserDetails();
      }
   }
   UserDetails userDetails;
   
   async Task LoadUserDetails()
   {
      userDetails = [read from server here];
      StateHasChanged();
   }
}
```

Now whilst this works, what I don't like very much is that the property setter in ChildComponent is synchronous, yet it is calling asynchronous code (LoadUserDetails).

What is the cleanest way of updating the UserId in the parent, and having the child realise this and calling an async method in response without blocking any threads?

Comment: override OnParametersSetAsync to load user details async

Comment: @aguafrommars but what about if there are multiple parameters? Can OnParametersSetAsync be sensitive to which parameter has changed, so that I can call the appropriate method?

Comment: You can check if the property changes by adding a flag in `UserId` setter

Comment: I can't really visualise how this would work.

Answer (score 3):

```cs
@code
{
   private int _userId;
   private bool _userIdChanged;
   
   [Parameter] public int UserId
   {
      get => _userId;
      set
      {
         _userIdChanged = value != _userId;
         _userId = value;
      }
   }
   UserDetails userDetails;
   
   async Task LoadUserDetails()
   {
      userDetails = [read from server here];
      StateHasChanged();
   }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
         await base.OnParametersSetAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
         if (_userIdChanged)
         {
             await LoadUserDetails().ConfigureAwait(false);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: The .ConfigureAwait() 's are not needed here and potentially harmful. How thread-safe is `[read from server here]` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman https://rules.sonarsource.com/csharp/RSPEC-3216

Comment: I find that a rather simplistic rule and the lack of specified conditions makes it useless. "Unless the rest of the code needs the context ..." , so when is that? It also looks rather dated. In Blazor (and WinForms, WPF, MVC) you should almost never need ConfigureAwait().  That StateHasChanged() won't work well on another thread.